# Google Maps as underlying map in React

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-geolocation

I have a caricatured map of a downtown. I would like, in my app, to show the user's location on this map, using google maps as the underlying map. Is it possible? If so, how do I map the user's geolocation from google maps into my map?

Using geolocation and google maps in an application using React, I want the app interface shows the user's location on a custom map.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting help. Your question seems to include multiple stuff that you should work on. It is recommended that we do some research first. I believe there are guides out there on how to implement Google Maps API using React. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e-5QHpadi0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.